# Getting the Id of an element Clicked.

Tags: jquery

am working on a filterable carousel and could use some help.

Here are the categories.

```
<div class="dslc-post-filters">
<span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-inactive" data-id=" ">All</span>
<span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-inactive" data-id="the-nurturer">The Nurturer</span>                                                                                 <span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-inactive" data-id="the-builder">The builder</span>                                                                               <span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-inactive" data-id="unifier">Unifier</span>                                                                                   <span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-active" data-id="explorer">Explorer</span>                                                                               <span class="dslc-post-filter dslc-inactive" data-id="the-creator">The Creator</span></div>
```

And here are the elements that are filtered.

```
<div class="dslc-posts dslc-partners dslc-clearfix dslc-posts-orientation-vertical dslc-init-grid "><div class="dslc-posts-inner">
    <div class="dslc-post dslc-partner dslc-col dslc-3-col  dslc-first-col" data-cats="the-nurturer " style="opacity: mysite;">



        <div class="dslc-post-thumb dslc-partner-thumb dslca-post-thumb dslc-on-hover-anim">
            <a href="mysitegiving/partner-view/test-6/"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/media/sites/86/2015/12/temp.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="temp"></a>


            </div><!-- .dslc-partner-thumb -->



            <div class="dslc-post-main dslc-partner-main">

                <div class="dslc-partner-title">
                    <h2><a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-6/">The Nurturer</a></h2>
                    </div><!-- .dslc-partner-title -->


                    <div class="dslc-partner-excerpt">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus tellus non dolor convallis imperdiet.…                                             </div><!-- .dslc-partner-excerpt -->

                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner-main -->

                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner -->

                        <div class="dslc-post dslc-partner dslc-col dslc-3-col " data-cats="the-builder " style="opacity: mysite;">



                            <div class="dslc-post-thumb dslc-partner-thumb dslca-post-thumb dslc-on-hover-anim">
                                <a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-5/"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/media/sites/86/2015/12/temp.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="temp"></a>


                                </div><!-- .dslc-partner-thumb -->



                                <div class="dslc-post-main dslc-partner-main">

                                    <div class="dslc-partner-title">
                                        <h2><a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-5/">The Builder</a></h2>
                                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner-title -->


                                        <div class="dslc-partner-excerpt">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus tellus non dolor convallis imperdiet.…                                             </div><!-- .dslc-partner-excerpt -->

                                            </div><!-- .dslc-partner-main -->

                                            </div><!-- .dslc-partner -->

                                            <div class="dslc-post dslc-partner dslc-col dslc-3-col " data-cats="unifier " style="opacity: mysite;">



                                                <div class="dslc-post-thumb dslc-partner-thumb dslca-post-thumb dslc-on-hover-anim">
                                                    <a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-4/"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/media/sites/86/2015/12/temp.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="temp"></a>


                                                    </div><!-- .dslc-partner-thumb -->



                                                    <div class="dslc-post-main dslc-partner-main">

                                                        <div class="dslc-partner-title">
                                                            <h2><a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-4/">Unifier</a></h2>
                                                            </div><!-- .dslc-partner-title -->


                                                            <div class="dslc-partner-excerpt">
                                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus tellus non dolor convallis imperdiet.…                                             </div><!-- .dslc-partner-excerpt -->

                                                                </div><!-- .dslc-partner-main -->

                                                                </div><!-- .dslc-partner -->

                                                                <div class="dslc-post dslc-partner dslc-col dslc-3-col  dslc-last-col" data-cats="explorer " style="opacity: 1;">



                                                                    <div class="dslc-post-thumb dslc-partner-thumb dslca-post-thumb dslc-on-hover-anim">
                                                                        <a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/tes-3/"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/media/sites/86/2015/12/temp.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="temp"></a>


                                                                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner-thumb -->



                                                                        <div class="dslc-post-main dslc-partner-main">

                                                                            <div class="dslc-partner-title">
                                                                                <h2><a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/tes-3/">Explorer</a></h2>
                                                                                </div><!-- .dslc-partner-title -->


                                                                                <div class="dslc-partner-excerpt">
                                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus tellus non dolor convallis imperdiet.…                                             </div><!-- .dslc-partner-excerpt -->

                                                                                    </div><!-- .dslc-partner-main -->

                                                                                    </div><!-- .dslc-partner -->

                                                                                    <div class="dslc-post dslc-partner dslc-col dslc-3-col  dslc-first-col" data-cats="the-creator " style="opacity: mysite;">



                                                                                        <div class="dslc-post-thumb dslc-partner-thumb dslca-post-thumb dslc-on-hover-anim">
                                                                                            <a href="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/partner-view/test-2/"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://mysite.colostate.edu/giving/media/sites/86/2015/12/temp.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="temp"></a>


                                                                                            </div><!-- .dslc-partner-thumb -->



                                                                                            <div class="dslc-post-main dslc-partner-main">

                                                                                                <div class="dslc-partner-title">
                                                                                                    <h2><a href="mysite/giving/partner-view/test-2/">The Creator</a></h2>
                                                                                                    </div><!-- .dslc-partner-title -->


                                                                                                    <div class="dslc-partner-excerpt">
                                                                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel lectus a arcu pretium lobortis…                                              </div><!-- .dslc-partner-excerpt -->

                                                                                                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner-main -->

                                                                                                        </div><!-- .dslc-partner -->

                                                                                                        </div><!-- .dslc-posts-inner -->
                                                                                                    </div>
```

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is this.

1.) When a dslc-post-filter is clicked on the data id is captured
2.) All posts that don't have the "data_cats" of clicked element are hidden.

I am thinking:

1.) I am using $(this).click then
2.) I don't know how to capture that ID, do I use ?
3.) After that am thinking I would use .find () and .not(" cat id that was captured in 2")
4.) Hide those elements

I understand the concept, just not sure how to put it together.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking about... Use line breaks, numbers and more specially clean english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dslc-post-filter').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        //HIDE ALL DESIRED ELEMENTS
    });
});
```

Assuming it is in its own `.js` file, otherwise put it in a script tag.

Comment: thanks! I can't seem to access that variable $(this).click(function() {
   var currentIMData = $(this).attr('data-id');
 console.log($(currentIMData));
});

Comment: @Deedub If you're trying to print the value of the variable after assigning it you don't use the `$()` syntax, use standard JS logging like this: `console.log(currentIMData);`. Using the code I gave you, that variable is now just a string containing the `id` of the element, not the element itself.

Comment: thanks! yeah I didn't work, so was trying different ways thining it's they way I called it

Comment: it's returning "Undefined."

Comment: @Deedub how are you implementing the script, a separate included `.js` or within a `script` tag?

Comment: I got it, thanks, it was user error. I am doing it using docoument ready in the head file for now.

Comment: @Deedub don't forget to upvote answers that helped and accept the best one!

Comment: ok I did that. thanks. just out of curiosity, $('[data-cats="'+ selector + ' "]').hide();. How do I tell it to hide all other ones except this one. Am trying to use not but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer I didn't read all that code. But to answer your question "How to get the id of the clicked element?" Put a class on the element and add the event listener to that class, then get the element id in the callback function

```
<div class='filter' id='foo'></div>
<script>
$('.filter').on('click', function(e){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
</script>
```

My jQuery skills are sub-par, so the code might need a tweak or two but that basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.dslc-post-filter').on("click",function() // delegate a click event to the elements with class 'dslc-post-filter'
{

    var selector = $(this).data("id"); // extract the data attr id
    if($.trim(selector) === "") // if it's empty , show all the sections
       $('.dslc-partner').show();
    else
    {
        $('.dslc-partner').hide(); // if not , hide all the sections
        $('.dslc-partner[data-cats=' + selector + ']').show(); // locate the element with class 'dslc-partner' and data-cats attribute equal to the data attr id of the element clicked and show it.
    }
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/cjb95996/3/

Comment: Thanks, I see that works, am trying to figure out what it doesn't on mine

Comment: Its because you have a space in data-cats.  data-cats="the-nurturer ". You can't have space in selectors.

Comment: it gets rid of the all of them :(